# In Processing, which is the fastest way to delete previous text

Tags: text, processing, erase

I tried to rewrite text with the backgroud color, but the edge (outline) of the old text remains on the screen. I have no idea why. Can you please help me?

```java
background(-1);
noLoop();
fill(#500F0F);
text("99", 300, 200);
fill(-1);
text("99",300, 200);
```

[Outcome:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAPOz.png)

Comment: why don't you simply clear the whole screen with `background()` ?

Answer (score 1):

In the future, please try to post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code in your post draws the text completely off the screen, which makes me wonder what else is different in your real code. Are you using a `draw()` function? Please avoid these uncertainties by posting a MCVE.

Anyway, your basic problem is caused by [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing). By default, Processing uses anti-aliasing to make drawings appear more smooth and less pixelated. You can see this if you zoom in to a drawing and notice the edges are a bit blurry. This is a good thing for most drawings, but in your case it's causing the blurry edges to show through.

So, to fix that problem, you could disable anti-aliasing by calling the `noSmooth()` function:

```java
size(500, 500);
noSmooth();
background(255);
noLoop();
fill(#500F0F);
text("99", 300, 200);
fill(255);
text("99",300, 200);
```

Also notice that I'm using `255` as a paramter instead of `-1`. I'm not sure what a color parameter of `-1` is supposed to do, so I'd keep it between `0` and `255` just to be safe.

But it's a little fishy that you need to "delete" any text in the first place. Like George's comment says, why don't you just call the `background()` function to clear out old frames?

Here's a small example:

```java
void draw() {
  background(64);
  if (mousePressed) {
    text("hello", 20, 40);
  }
}
```